# PHP File Upload Error

Tags: php, file, input, upload, xampp

**HTML**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="SubmitForm" method="post" action="serv.php">
  <input type="file" name="IMG" size="chars">
  <input type="Submit" value="SAVE">
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
$target = 'upload/';
$target = $target . basename($_FILES['IMG']['name']);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['IMG']['tmp_name'], $target)) {           //line 66
    echo 'File uploaded successfully';
} else {
    echo 'Sorry, there was a problem uploading file'
}
```

**PROBLEMS**

> **Warning:** move_uploaded_file(upload/image.jpg) **[function.move-uploaded-file]**: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **C:\xampp\htdocs\test\include\pages\editor\ged.php** on line **66**
>
> **Warning:** move_uploaded_file() **[function.move-uploaded-file]**: Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php5E.tmp' to 'upload/image.jpg' in **C:\xampp\htdocs\test\include\pages\editor\ged.php** on line **66**
>
> Sorry, there was a problem uploading file

I had added a file existence check and it passed, proving the file exists. I believe the problem lies somewhere within the PHP code I specified here.

Also, I've used a similar code on an earlier script and it worked. I expected this to be no different. I am beginning to think the problem is related to how the temporary file is handled? I do not know, which is why I'm here.

Apologies if this thread is a clone but all or any previous threads bearing a similar name provided solutions that did not prove to be useful for me (in my scenario).

Any help or advice is appreciated greatly. Where am I going wrong? And how can this be corrected?

Comment: does `upload/` exist? Do you mean `./upload/`

Comment: Does `C:\xampp\htdocs\test\include\pages\editor\upload` exist?

Comment: What in $_FILES["IMG"]["error"]? var_dump($_FILES["IMG"]["error"]);

Comment: var_dump($_FILES["IMG"]["error"]); is int(0)

Comment: try using `getcwd()` to create the absolute path just in case, try not to hard code it, since it makes it hard to deploy the system on other machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, we have two PHP files involved, `serv.php` and `ged.php`, and it sounds like they are located in different directories. If you use relative paths in such layout, the path is interpreted by default as relative to the main script location, i.e. `serv.php`. So you want this:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\test\include\pages\editor\upload
```

... but it's possible that PHP is looking for e.g. this:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\test\upload
```

The simplest fix is to use absolute paths.

Comment: Thanks. The upload folder required that I put it in the same directory as serv.php.

Answer (score 1):

The `$target` upload refers to `C:\xampp\htdocs\test\include\pages\editor\upload\`. It sounds like this folder doesn't exist or doesn't have write permissions.

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure It exists. And I see no reason why is should be write protected.

Comment: Try changing `"upload/"` to `"upload\"`. Windows might be having issues with the incorrect Directory Separator.

Comment: Alternatively, also try changing to an absolute path. The `upload` file might be relastive to `serv.php` if `serv.php` includes `ged.php`

Comment: "\" character is an Escape Sequence. Adding it messes up the string.

Comment: the 'upload' folder in in the 'editor' directory. The same which houses the ged.php. It is relative to ged.php.

Comment: it must be relative to serv.php, if you include sed in serv.php. See my answer.

Comment: regarding '\' being an escape character, you can escape it :) try '\\' instead of '\' - Windows doesn't use "/" as directory separator (not to say "/" doesn't work, but really you should stick to what it expects...)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my english ;o)
Error in include file. But the directory "upload" must be in the same directory with file serv.php if you include ged.php in serv.php.

```
htdocs/.../ -
   upload - dir
   serv.php - file
   ... other files and directories
```

Comment: Thanks. The upload folder required that I put it in the same directory as serv.php.